# Google Cloud App Engine SSL URLS are not updating after deployment (non-ssl does)

Tags: google-app-engine

I successfully deploy a new version to App Engine, then delete the older version via the Google Cloud Console.  100% traffic is pointed to the new instance.  I checked the source code, it's all correct.

When I visit the non-SSL URL,  everything is updated and works as expected within minutes every time.

When going to the SSL URL, it's cached from an older version which doesn't not exist. It can take hours to see the update.  I've tried with Private Mode Safari and Incognito Chrome, same issue)

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Is there a way to force the SSL version to refresh like the non-SSL version?

Comment: Are these static files?

Comment: No, it's reactjs.

Comment: What you are describing is not possible.  You are misunderstanding something about what is going on.

Comment: Why do you say it's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Closing this post.  After a hard refresh, the cache updated.   I was using a soft refresh.

If anyone uses reactjs / javascript, make sure to use

window.location.reload(true)

vs

window.location.reload();

with true, it's a hard cache refresh.

If you're using TSX, just add //@ts-ingnore before the line.